# Split or replaceState to remove an anchor tag from a URL?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On our landing pages, we have a call-to-action button that moves the user to an anchor on the page. But the addition of an anchor tag in the URL is messing up our tracking data.

I have come up with two solutions: `split` and `replaceState`. The `split` doesn't seem to work consistently, depending on the anchor tag. The `replaceState` works perfectly, but the boss says it's sub-optimal.

Which one is the best and how do I optimize it?

**split**

```
$form.find('[name="source_url"]').val(location.href.split('#')[0]);
```

**replaceState**

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.href.split('#')[0]);
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

Comment: Please take the time to take the [Tour](https://superuser.com/tour) and read the [Help pages](https://superuser.com/help), especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://superuser.com/help/dont-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Both the `split` and `replaceState` methods can be used to remove the anchor tag from the URL. Let's compare both approaches and discuss their pros and cons.

1. Using `split`:

```
$form.find('[name="source_url"]').val(location.href.split('#')[0]);
```

This method directly splits the URL using the `#` character as a delimiter and takes the part before the anchor tag. It seems like you're setting the value of an input field with the URL without the anchor tag.

Pros:

- Simple and straightforward to implement.
- Works well when the URL structure is consistent and the anchor tag is always at the end.

Cons:

- If the URL structure varies or if the anchor tag is not always at the end, this method might not work as expected.

2. Using `replaceState`:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.href.split('#')[0]);
    }
  }, 500);
});
```

This method listens for changes in the hash part of the URL (anchor tag changes) and replaces the current state of the URL with the part before the anchor tag.

Pros:

- More flexible, as it dynamically removes the anchor tag whenever it appears in the URL.
- Works for various URL structures and anchor tag placements.

Cons:

- It involves setting up an event listener, which may add a slight overhead.

If the `split` method is not consistently working for all cases, and `replaceState` works perfectly, then you might want to go with the `replaceState` approach. The boss might consider it sub-optimal because it introduces an event listener, but in most cases, the performance impact is negligible.

To optimize the `replaceState` approach:

1. Reduce the timeout value: Instead of using `setTimeout` with 500 milliseconds, try reducing it to a lower value (e.g., 100 milliseconds) to make the URL update more responsive while still avoiding any potential tracking issues.
2. Debouncing the event: Depending on your application, you could consider debouncing the `hashchange` event to prevent excessive calls to `replaceState` within a short time span. This way, you can ensure that the function is called only after a certain interval of inactivity to avoid unnecessary updates.

Here's an example of how you could debounce the event:

```js
let timerId;
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  clearTimeout(timerId);
  timerId = setTimeout(function() {
    if (window.location.hash) {
      history.replaceState('', document.title, window.location.href.split('#')[0]);
    }
  }, 100); // Adjust the debounce interval as needed
});
```

Remember, the best approach depends on the specific requirements of your application and the consistency of your URL structure. If the `split` method works consistently for your specific use case, it might be the simpler and more performant choice. However, if you encounter issues with it, the `replaceState` approach with some optimizations is a good alternative.

Comment: Please try to resist the temptation to answer off-topic questions - it gives people the [unfortunately now correct] impression they can ask anything & get an answer. See: [Tag for JavaScript exists but it is off-topic on Super User](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/12883/tag-for-javascript-exists-but-it-is-off-topic-on-super-user) The tag itself says it's off-topic - https://i.stack.imgur.com/PZGPh.png